# How to check if a table in sqlite python has changed?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I have a database with a lot of similar tables, and I have a program that will update the existing tables.
I also have a flask project which displays those tables. My final goal is to make the Flask app change the information on the open page **without** the user having to reload it. I have figured out how to do so, but I now need to know when a table has been updated.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach 1:
You can use ajax to reload the content in the table at a regular interval.

```
setTimeout(function,milliseconds)
setInterval(function, milliseconds)
```

Use any one of the Javascript function to fire the ajax at each interval.

Approach 2:
Add this tag inside HTML head tag. It will refresh the page automatically,

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

Approach 3:
If you don't want to refresh the page, or don't want to use ajax, then you can try `socket`. In this way, we can create our page to change whenever there is a change in the database. (like Chat App)

Comment: Well the whole idea is actually a discord replica that uses a bot, so I'l try sockets

Comment: How would I connect the socket to both my database and flask app?

Comment: @PythonSnek. Check `python-socketio` modeule